# Rotate text -90deg and vertically align with div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to vertically align text that has been rotated by -90deg and not having much luck. Code below

HTML:

```
<section class="page_block" style="background: <?php echo $background; ?>;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 class="verticaltext">
                    <?php echo $page->post_title; ?>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <p><?php echo $page->post_content; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```css
.page_block {
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
}
#header { 
    position: relative; 
}
.verticaltext {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: right, top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:right, top;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:right, top;

    position: absolute; bottom: 0%; left: 0%;
    color: #ed217c;
}
```

The result is [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t8h0.jpg).
This is a Wordpress theme, with Twitter Bootstrap implemented as well as a full width slider. I have confirmed that both Bootstrap and the Slider do not contain conflicting CSS.

Comment: How do you want the text to be aligned? Center?

Comment: Yes please, that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've had to give up on the CSS front and generate the titles as transparent PNGs using GD. Not ideal, but gives me a lot more flexibility in terms of positioning. If anyone is interested in the rotation script I'm using, it's below

```
define("DEFAULT_FONT", "fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf");
define("DEFAULT_COLOR", "ed217c");
define("DEFAULT_SIZE", 24);
define("DEFAULT_ANGLE", 0);
define("DEFAULT_PADDING", 10);
define("DEFAULT_SPACING", 0);

$text = $_GET['text'];
if(isset($_GET['transform'])):
    switch ($_GET['transform']){
        case 'uc':
            $text = strtoupper($_GET['text']);
            break;

        case 'lc':
            $text = strtolower($_GET['text']);
            break;

        case 'ucf':
            $text = ucfirst($_GET['text']);
            break;

        case 'ucw':
            $text = ucwords($_GET['text']);
            break;
    }
endif;

$font = $_GET['font'] ? $_GET['font'] : DEFAULT_FONT;
$color = (strlen($_GET['color']) == 6 && ctype_alnum($_GET['color']))  ? "0x" . $_GET['color'] : "0x" . DEFAULT_COLOR;
$size = (is_numeric($_GET['size'])) ? $_GET['size'] : DEFAULT_SIZE;
$angle = (is_numeric($_GET['angle'])) ? $_GET['angle'] : DEFAULT_ANGLE;
$padding = (is_numeric($_GET['padding'])) ? $_GET['padding']*4 : DEFAULT_PADDING*4;
$spacing = (is_numeric($_GET['spacing'])) ? $_GET['spacing'] : DEFAULT_SPACING;
$text_dimensions = calculateTextDimensions($text, $font, $size, $angle, $spacing);
$image_width = $text_dimensions["width"] + $padding;
$image_height = $text_dimensions["height"] + $padding;

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($image_width, $image_height);
ImageFill($new_image, 0, 0, IMG_COLOR_TRANSPARENT);
imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
imagealphablending($new_image, false);
imagettftextSp($new_image, $size, $angle, $text_dimensions["left"] + ($image_width / 2) - ($text_dimensions["width"] / 2), $text_dimensions["top"] + ($image_height / 2) - ($text_dimensions["height"] / 2), $color, $font, $text, $spacing);
imagepng($new_image);
imagerotate($new_image, 90, 0);
imagedestroy($new_image);

function imagettftextSp($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text, $spacing = 0)
{
    if ($spacing == 0)
    {
        imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text);
    }
    else
    {
        $temp_x = $x;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++)
        {
            $bbox = imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $temp_x, $y, $color, $font, $text[$i]);
            $temp_x += $spacing + ($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]);
        }
    }
}

function calculateTextDimensions($text, $font, $size, $angle, $spacing) {
    $rect = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $font, $text);
    $minX = min(array($rect[0],$rect[2],$rect[4],$rect[6]));
    $maxX = max(array($rect[0],$rect[2],$rect[4],$rect[6]));
    $minY = min(array($rect[1],$rect[3],$rect[5],$rect[7]));
    $maxY = max(array($rect[1],$rect[3],$rect[5],$rect[7]));
    $spacing = ($spacing*(strlen($text)+2));
    return array(
        "left"   => abs($minX) - 1,
        "top"    => abs($minY) - 1,
        "width"  => ($maxX - $minX)+$spacing,
        "height" => $maxY - $minY,
        "box"    => $rect
    );
}
    header("content-type: image/png");
```

Modified from Jason Lau's awesome script, which can be found [here](http://jasonlau.biz/home/php/image-text-with-custom-font-using-php-and-gd).

Answer (score 12):

Not sure why you had `bottom: 0%; left: 0%;` in the first place, but removing them results in your desired goal I believe.

### [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/KV84j/)

### CSS:

```
.page_block {
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
}
#header { 
    position: relative; 
}
.verticaltext {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: right, top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:right, top;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:right, top;
    position: absolute; 
    color: #ed217c;
}
```

Comment: Afraid not, the text doesn't sit in the centre of the div. See screenshot here

http://i.imgur.com/ufHBsIw.jpg

Comment: I had to slightly/significantly change your HTML and CSS in that one so pay close attention

Comment: Doesn't help as you're changing the entire layout, the heading sits in 1 col to the left, and the content takes up the other 11 cols. Your solution destroys any responsiveness that has been implemented through Bootstrap.

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what the issue was? I'm not really sure and only achieved the fix through trial and error, so an explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="vertical">Vertical Text Here</div>
    <div>
        <div>Horizontal Text Here</div>
        ...
        <div>Horizontal Text Here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.container{
     display: grid;
     grid-auto-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content);
     grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.vertical{
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     writing-mode: vertical-lr;
     text-align: center;
}
```

## Explanation

### To achieve -90 deg text

`writing-mode: vertical-lr` writes text vertically but is basically equivalent to rotating the text 90 degrees. With `transform: rotate(180deg)` we end up with the -90 degrees look we want.

### To vertically align rotated text

I used `grid` and `grid-template-columns` to put the rotated text beside the div. This way the div can hold multiple lines or other things. Use `text-align` to align the rotated text however you want. In this case it's `center`.

**note:** You may not need: `grid-auto-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content)`. If the rotated text's height does weird things, this can used to force wrap the rotated text to fit its content.

Answer (score 3):

There is a CSS property that rotates text and orients the containing blocks: [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

Here is a [JS Fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jgrumpers/c2z3mnh1/30/)

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to achieve the same effect as Deruck but without changing the structure of the html.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bb5k/5/)

```css
body{
    margin:0;
}
p{
    margin: 0;
}
.page_block {
    margin:0px;
}
.row{
    position: relative;
}
.col-md-11{
    margin-left:50px;
}
.verticaltext {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

    bottom: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    color: #ed217c;
}
```